# because he "could" or "could've" in the past tense

Tags: modal-verbs, past-simple

I didn't call him because he **could** be busy.

I didn't call him because he **could've** been busy.

To mean "I didn't call him, thinking he could be busy," which sentence would you use? Also, what are the differences in the meaning between the given sentences here?

Answer (score 0):

"I didn't call him" is in past tense, and therefore you cannot use "could be busy", especially since "could" has no tense, and there are no other words to depict a past tense in the sentnece.

> I didn't call him because he could've been busy.

This ^ is correct as it is "could have been busy" - and "could have" depicts how something might have happened in the past, e.g.

> I could have caught my flight if it wasn't for the delay

Answer (score -1):

I think might is better: I didn't call him because he might be busy.

I didn't call him because he would have be busy.
means
I thought he was busy, but actually he wasn't busy.